# Creating a simple form with a reference to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a simple form to create a Student instance. The student belongs to a library (it has a library_id column in its table). What would be the best way to create this simple form so when the student is filling the form the see a dropdown of all libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `collection_select` helper:

```
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :library_id, Library.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```